# DisplayMemberPath for several properties in ListView

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, .net-4.0, properties

I've got simple class

```
public class Person
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    string Path { get; set; }
}
```

I've got also System.Windows.Controls.ListView containing several this type objects.

I'd like to show both properties (or more if it will be) in this ListView.

If I have one I know I can do this using DisplayMemberPath:

```
<ListView DisplayMemberPath="Name" Name="listViewClients" />
```

But how can I get result like this:

```
"Name: Path"
```

(I mean of course values of this properties for appropiate object)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this is, create another readonly property to wrap them up.

```
string NamePath { get { return Name + ": " + Path; }}
```

then you can just set the DisplayMemberPath to NamePath

Answer (score 3):

You could also override the `ToString()` method and omit setting `DisplayMemberPath`, which might be more elegant in some cases:

```
public class Person
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    string Path { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name + ": " + Path;
    }
}
```